# How to append regex result to existing txt file in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, ip

Lets say I have an existing text file that contains IP address.

ip_list.txt

```
192.168.1.1
10.135.135.2
```

I am running a script that takes raw json each containing an IP address which then grep the IP out using regex and appends it to a file. However it has been appending blank lines. Im not a good bash user so it may even be a just a syntax error.

```
ip = $(grep -Eo '(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' '$1')

echo "$ip" >> /root/temp/ip_list.txt
```

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like I am close.

If i run `grep -Eo '(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' 'log_file.txt`

I dont run into any issues.

Comment: `ip = $(grep` => `ip=$(grep`, there should be no spaces round the `=`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I removed the spaces around the ```=``` and it made no difference in the result. I am still getting blank lines unfortunately.

Comment: Try `ip=$(grep -Eo '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' "$1"'` if `$1` is the file path, see https://ideone.com/yeFQgZ

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the double quotes around $1 was the solution. It was driving me nuts!!! Thank you so much. I really appreciate the advice.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed you have single quotes there. They prevent variable expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should removes spaces on both sides of `=` and make sure to use double quotation marks around `$1` to allow variable expansion (it is not performed inside single quotes):

```
ip=$(grep -Eo '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' "$1")
```

I also use a bit shortened IP regex pattern.

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/yeFQgZ):

```
f="192.168.1.1
10.135.135.2"
ip=$(grep -Eo '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' <<< "$f")
echo "$ip"
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.1
10.135.135.2
```